# How to Click a Link on a IE webpage?

Tags: button, vbscript, hyperlink

I want to open a button named 'Open' in IE window using VBScript. Source code is like this:

```html
<a title="Devtems Life Menu" href="javascript:OpenOryx('cboClone');">Open</a>
```

Comment: Try posting some code

Comment: At least post the source code of yhis web page !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start answering the question, I just want to say that I am by no means an expert at VBScript. My knowledge is based off a lot of messing around with it during weekends and a bit of read the documentation. There may be better ways of doing things, but this works for me.

My recommendation is if you have access to the html, add an attribute to your link so it looks something like this:

```
<a title="Devtems Life Menu" href="javascript:OpenOryx('cboClone');" id="openMenu">Open</a>
```

Then you can easily reference it in your code. If you can't access the html,  then you may have to use a more roundabout way of checking the contents of each link. The actual syntax is described below in a little script I constructed. It firstly loads w3schools.com, then clicks on the references tab. This uses `ie.document.getElementById(arg)`. Notice that the references navigation panel opens. After that it will prompt you to click the ok button to continue. It will then load google.com, and look through all the `<a>` tags. If it contains Open it clicks on it. You can use the same syntax, except different details for your script.

```
' Create the ie object
set ie = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
' Navigate to wherever you want
ie.navigate("http://www.w3schools.com/")
ie.Visible = true
' Call the subroutine we define below
waitForPage(ie)

' Get link by id
' This is a one liner, and I personally think is better than the method below
' first of all you get the tag you want by id
' then you click it
ie.document.getElementById("navbtn_references").click()
' call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("w3_open_nav('references')", "JavaScript") 
' could also be written as:
'set buttonElement = ie.document.getElementById("navbtn_references")
'buttonElement.click()

MsgBox("Click ok to continue to google.")
' Load google
ie.navigate("https://google.com/")
' And wait for it to load
waitForPage(ie)
' Click on a link by attribute (same technique can be used for name etc)
' Get all elements with tag input
set linkElements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
' Then loop through them
for each possibleElement in linkElements
    ' If it has a certain name..
  if possibleElement.innerHtml = "About" then ' You could use If possibleElement.getAttribute("name") = "foo" Then or possibleElement.getAttribute("class") = "bar"
        ' Click it!
    possibleElement.click()
  end if
next
' Subroutine to wait for internet explorer to load a page
sub waitForPage(ie)
  do
    WScript.Sleep(100)
  loop while ie.ReadyState < 4
end sub
```

Another method is rather than actually finding and clicking on the link, you simply run the script that is run when a user normally clicks on a link. In your case, it could mean running `javascript:OpenOryx('cboClone');` directly. Here is how to run javascript code in VBScrpt:

```
call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("javascript:OpenOryx('cboClone');", "JavaScript")
```

I hope that at least one of these methods helps you in writing your script.

Comment: Need one more help. New window is displayed. How to activate the opened window. 
There is no URL as such. Could only see the title of window and the href.

Comment: Here is the source code of the opened window.



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
      CS400 - LIFEREP
</title><link type="text/css"
href="/app_Themes/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="/App_Themes/Corporate/Default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="/App_Themes/Corporate/jquery.dropdownlist.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/><link href="/App_Themes/Corporate/popup.css"
type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>